# Go struct inside of same struct type?

Tags: go, struct

I want a relationship between structs, example:

```
type A struct {
   X string
   Y int
   *A
}
```

It's possible this?
And if it's possible, what is the right way to marshal and unmarshal to JSON this?

When i marshal this struct to JSON the field A is lost.

Comment: Reminds me of a linked list node. Google some implementations, [here's one](https://gist.github.com/Maksadbek/f76f69198395d18338887a60fb08c7fa). Not sure how it turn it to JSON and back however.

Comment: Have you tried? It is valid code. What problem are you having?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What kind of relationship do you expect? Marshal to what?

Comment: when marshal to json this struct, the field A losts

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want. The question as it is now is too abstract to have a good answer.

Comment: @Stefano: The embedded `*A` fields are lost because they have the same names as the struct they are embedded in. You could fix this by unembedding `*A`: `A *A`.

Comment: ok, it's work!, thanks Tim.. thanks at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, but the anonimous filed A is lost because have the same names as the struct.
Solution:

```
type A struct {
   X string
   Y int
   Z *A
}
```

Comment: can you add a complete example how it works with your code ?